# Why am i getting this error? (Android)

Tags: java, android

"ColorPickerDialog.OnColorChangedListener cannot be resolved to a type" is the error i get in Eclipse in FingerPaint.java. The error is right below the import and one on the bottom. 
In ColorPickerDialog.java i have no errors.

Here is FingerPaint.java:

```
package izzy.n;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.*;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;

public class FingerPaint extends GraphicsActivity implements ColorPickerDialog.OnColorChangedListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(new MyView(this));

        mPaint = new Paint();
        mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        mPaint.setDither(true);
        mPaint.setColor(0xFFFF0000);
        mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        mPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
        mPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
        mPaint.setStrokeWidth(12);

        mEmboss = new EmbossMaskFilter(new float[] { 1, 1, 1 },
                                       0.4f, 6, 3.5f);

        mBlur = new BlurMaskFilter(8, BlurMaskFilter.Blur.NORMAL);
    }

    private Paint       mPaint;
    private MaskFilter  mEmboss;
    private MaskFilter  mBlur;

    public void colorChanged(int color) {
        mPaint.setColor(color);
    }

    public class MyView extends View {

        private static final float MINP = 0.25f;
        private static final float MAXP = 0.75f;

        private Bitmap  mBitmap;
        private Canvas  mCanvas;
        private Path    mPath;
        private Paint   mBitmapPaint;

        public MyView(Context c) {
            super(c);

            mPath = new Path();
            mBitmapPaint = new Paint(Paint.DITHER_FLAG);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
            super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
            mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
            mCanvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
            canvas.drawColor(0xFFAAAAAA);

            canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, 0, 0, mBitmapPaint);

            canvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
        }

        private float mX, mY;
        private static final float TOUCH_TOLERANCE = 4;

        private void touch_start(float x, float y) {
            mPath.reset();
            mPath.moveTo(x, y);
            mX = x;
            mY = y;
        }
        private void touch_move(float x, float y) {
            float dx = Math.abs(x - mX);
            float dy = Math.abs(y - mY);
            if (dx >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE || dy >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE) {
                mPath.quadTo(mX, mY, (x + mX)/2, (y + mY)/2);
                mX = x;
                mY = y;
            }
        }
        private void touch_up() {
            mPath.lineTo(mX, mY);
            // commit the path to our offscreen
            mCanvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
            // kill this so we don't double draw
            mPath.reset();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
            float x = event.getX();
            float y = event.getY();

            switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    touch_start(x, y);
                    invalidate();
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    touch_move(x, y);
                    invalidate();
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    touch_up();
                    invalidate();
                    break;
            }
            return true;
        }
    }

    private static final int COLOR_MENU_ID = Menu.FIRST;
    private static final int EMBOSS_MENU_ID = Menu.FIRST + 1;
    private static final int BLUR_MENU_ID = Menu.FIRST + 2;
    private static final int ERASE_MENU_ID = Menu.FIRST + 3;
    private static final int SRCATOP_MENU_ID = Menu.FIRST + 4;

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

        menu.add(0, COLOR_MENU_ID, 0, "Color").setShortcut('3', 'c');
        menu.add(0, EMBOSS_MENU_ID, 0, "Emboss").setShortcut('4', 's');
        menu.add(0, BLUR_MENU_ID, 0, "Blur").setShortcut('5', 'z');
        menu.add(0, ERASE_MENU_ID, 0, "Erase").setShortcut('5', 'z');
        menu.add(0, SRCATOP_MENU_ID, 0, "SrcATop").setShortcut('5', 'z');

        /****   Is this the mechanism to extend with filter effects?
        Intent intent = new Intent(null, getIntent().getData());
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_ALTERNATIVE);
        menu.addIntentOptions(
                              Menu.ALTERNATIVE, 0,
                              new ComponentName(this, NotesList.class),
                              null, intent, 0, null);
        *****/
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        mPaint.setXfermode(null);
        mPaint.setAlpha(0xFF);

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case COLOR_MENU_ID:
                new ColorPickerDialog(this, this, mPaint.getColor()).show();
                return true;
            case EMBOSS_MENU_ID:
                if (mPaint.getMaskFilter() != mEmboss) {
                    mPaint.setMaskFilter(mEmboss);
                } else {
                    mPaint.setMaskFilter(null);
                }
                return true;
            case BLUR_MENU_ID:
                if (mPaint.getMaskFilter() != mBlur) {
                    mPaint.setMaskFilter(mBlur);
                } else {
                    mPaint.setMaskFilter(null);
                }
                return true;
            case ERASE_MENU_ID:
                mPaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(
                                                        PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR));
                return true;
            case SRCATOP_MENU_ID:
                mPaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(
                                                    PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP));
                mPaint.setAlpha(0x80);
                return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Here is ColorPickerDialog.java:

```
package izzy.n;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.*;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;

public class ColorPickerDialog extends Dialog {

    public interface OnColorChangedListener {
        void colorChanged(int color);
    }

    private OnColorChangedListener mListener;
    private int mInitialColor;

    private static class ColorPickerView extends View {
        private Paint mPaint;
        private Paint mCenterPaint;
        private final int[] mColors;
        private OnColorChangedListener mListener;

        ColorPickerView(Context c, OnColorChangedListener l, int color) {
            super(c);
            mListener = l;
            mColors = new int[] {
                0xFFFF0000, 0xFFFF00FF, 0xFF0000FF, 0xFF00FFFF, 0xFF00FF00,
                0xFFFFFF00, 0xFFFF0000
            };
            Shader s = new SweepGradient(0, 0, mColors, null);

            mPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
            mPaint.setShader(s);
            mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
            mPaint.setStrokeWidth(32);

            mCenterPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
            mCenterPaint.setColor(color);
            mCenterPaint.setStrokeWidth(5);
        }

        private boolean mTrackingCenter;
        private boolean mHighlightCenter;

        @Override
        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
            float r = CENTER_X - mPaint.getStrokeWidth()*0.5f;

            canvas.translate(CENTER_X, CENTER_X);

            canvas.drawOval(new RectF(-r, -r, r, r), mPaint);
            canvas.drawCircle(0, 0, CENTER_RADIUS, mCenterPaint);

            if (mTrackingCenter) {
                int c = mCenterPaint.getColor();
                mCenterPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);

                if (mHighlightCenter) {
                    mCenterPaint.setAlpha(0xFF);
                } else {
                    mCenterPaint.setAlpha(0x80);
                }
                canvas.drawCircle(0, 0,
                                  CENTER_RADIUS + mCenterPaint.getStrokeWidth(),
                                  mCenterPaint);

                mCenterPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
                mCenterPaint.setColor(c);
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
            setMeasuredDimension(CENTER_X*2, CENTER_Y*2);
        }

        private static final int CENTER_X = 100;
        private static final int CENTER_Y = 100;
        private static final int CENTER_RADIUS = 32;

        private int floatToByte(float x) {
            int n = java.lang.Math.round(x);
            return n;
        }
        private int pinToByte(int n) {
            if (n < 0) {
                n = 0;
            } else if (n > 255) {
                n = 255;
            }
            return n;
        }

        private int ave(int s, int d, float p) {
            return s + java.lang.Math.round(p * (d - s));
        }

        private int interpColor(int colors[], float unit) {
            if (unit <= 0) {
                return colors[0];
            }
            if (unit >= 1) {
                return colors[colors.length - 1];
            }

            float p = unit * (colors.length - 1);
            int i = (int)p;
            p -= i;

            // now p is just the fractional part [0...1) and i is the index
            int c0 = colors[i];
            int c1 = colors[i+1];
            int a = ave(Color.alpha(c0), Color.alpha(c1), p);
            int r = ave(Color.red(c0), Color.red(c1), p);
            int g = ave(Color.green(c0), Color.green(c1), p);
            int b = ave(Color.blue(c0), Color.blue(c1), p);

            return Color.argb(a, r, g, b);
        }

        private int rotateColor(int color, float rad) {
            float deg = rad * 180 / 3.1415927f;
            int r = Color.red(color);
            int g = Color.green(color);
            int b = Color.blue(color);

            ColorMatrix cm = new ColorMatrix();
            ColorMatrix tmp = new ColorMatrix();

            cm.setRGB2YUV();
            tmp.setRotate(0, deg);
            cm.postConcat(tmp);
            tmp.setYUV2RGB();
            cm.postConcat(tmp);

            final float[] a = cm.getArray();

            int ir = floatToByte(a[0] * r +  a[1] * g +  a[2] * b);
            int ig = floatToByte(a[5] * r +  a[6] * g +  a[7] * b);
            int ib = floatToByte(a[10] * r + a[11] * g + a[12] * b);

            return Color.argb(Color.alpha(color), pinToByte(ir),
                              pinToByte(ig), pinToByte(ib));
        }

        private static final float PI = 3.1415926f;

        @Override
        public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
            float x = event.getX() - CENTER_X;
            float y = event.getY() - CENTER_Y;
            boolean inCenter = java.lang.Math.sqrt(x*x + y*y) <= CENTER_RADIUS;

            switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    mTrackingCenter = inCenter;
                    if (inCenter) {
                        mHighlightCenter = true;
                        invalidate();
                        break;
                    }
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    if (mTrackingCenter) {
                        if (mHighlightCenter != inCenter) {
                            mHighlightCenter = inCenter;
                            invalidate();
                        }
                    } else {
                        float angle = (float)java.lang.Math.atan2(y, x);
                        // need to turn angle [-PI ... PI] into unit [0....1]
                        float unit = angle/(2*PI);
                        if (unit < 0) {
                            unit += 1;
                        }
                        mCenterPaint.setColor(interpColor(mColors, unit));
                        invalidate();
                    }
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    if (mTrackingCenter) {
                        if (inCenter) {
                            mListener.colorChanged(mCenterPaint.getColor());
                        }
                        mTrackingCenter = false;    // so we draw w/o halo
                        invalidate();
                    }
                    break;
            }
            return true;
        }
    }

    public ColorPickerDialog(Context context,
                             OnColorChangedListener listener,
                             int initialColor) {
        super(context);

        mListener = listener;
        mInitialColor = initialColor;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        OnColorChangedListener l = new OnColorChangedListener() {
            public void colorChanged(int color) {
                mListener.colorChanged(color);
                dismiss();
            }
        };

        setContentView(new ColorPickerView(getContext(), l, mInitialColor));
        setTitle("Pick a Color");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

rapidshare.com/files/159873389/Testing_Images.rar

try this project this one is similar to one you are trying you will find this useful

Comment: This is the same one u just gave me, but i still get this error..

Comment: ur still geting this error even in my project??

Comment: Yes :(  ColorPickerDialog.OnColorChangedListener is underlined in eclipse that its not resolved maybe you know?

Comment: have you tried cleaning up the project and organising imports restart eclipse ??

Comment: Restarted eclipse :) no errors. Im gonna add The layout now. Im not adding the gallery.java file because i get a whole bunch of errors.

Comment: try importing the project as it is into the eclipse

Comment: I would lol but never knew how to do that. :(

Comment: wait, but is it okay if i rename main.xml into main2.xml? what Should i change in the java to make it be called in correctly?

Comment: ok no follow this step rightclick on navigator pane in android and select new android project click on create from existing it will let you browse the project cllick on finish and there you go!!!

Comment: No, but im putting all of this in my existing project im not starting a new one. All i need to know is where do you declare main.xml in the java so i can change it from main.xml to main2.xml?

Comment: there is no xml file because the canvas is generated programatically

Comment: So why is there main.xml in the res folder?

Comment: it's useless I created this project long time back

Comment: Okay! One more question im really sorry. So how can i have a button that takes me to the activity(paint) from an xml file.

Comment: you need this button on the canvas where you draw or you want navigation to this FingerPaint class

Comment: Exactly so how do i navigate to fingerpaint? Like this? 
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.FingerPaint);
  
 


  Button wg = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
  wg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
   public void onClick(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
    finish();

Comment: Thanks everything worked! But how is it possible to save the drawing? Is it possible?

Comment: press menu button you will find option over there in more

Comment: I did and there is no "more" only color,blur,emboss,erase,and srcatop.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
 public interface OnColorChangedListener {
        void colorChanged(int color);
    }
```

change to static interface like this:

```
 public static interface OnColorChangedListener {
            void colorChanged(int color);
        }
```